# Long transit layover in Montreal: is it possible to leave the airport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, layovers, eta, montreal

I have a Las Vegas to Rome flight booked with Air Canada, which gives me an 11-hour layover in Montreal. My luggage will go directly through to Rome from Las Vegas, so I won't need to get it in Montreal.

I already have my eTA for transit through Canada. Can I leave the airport for a sightseeing tour of Montreal? Will it be okay with Customs & Immigration? I'll carry just a small carry-on backpack with me.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. This is done commonly. When entering Montreal, they will ask you how long will yo stay. Just say 11 hours (or so) and, if asked, show them your onward boarding pass. There is nothing that requires a minimum duration or prior planning to use the eTA. Be sure to leave enough time to come back ahead of your flight since you will have to pass security again.